# Position of character to the left of current position in string

Tags: c#, string, indexing

From some arbitrary position in a string I need to find the closest position of a character to the left of my position. If I want to perform this operation to the right I could just use `.IndexOf`, but how to do it to the left I am unsure.

The two ways I came up with were just a decrementing loop starting at my position or, putting the string in reverse and using a normal `.IndexOf`

Anyone else have any better ways of achieving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about:

```
yourstring.LastIndexOf("foo", 0, currentPosition)
```

Comment: Well hows about that, by far an easier solution that I was working towards.

Answer (score 0):

More explicitly, find *word* occurring before *nWord* in *txt*: Your word will be at position *s*:

```
Dim s As Integer = txt.Substring(0, txt.IndexOf(nWord)).LastIndexOf(word)
```

This was useful to me in a loop where I needed to find all occurrences.

This is how to construct the loop:

```
Dim n As Integer = 0
Dim s As Integer = 0
Do While txt.Contains(word) AndAlso txt.Contains(nWord)
     n = txt.IndexOf(nWord)
     'n = txt.IndexOf(nWord)+nWord.Length ':If nWord may also contain word
     s += txt.Substring(0, n).LastIndexOf(word)
     txt = txt.SubString(n + nWord.Length)
     MsgBox("Found at " & s.ToString())
Loop
```